# How do I echo something from Facebook's graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display the content from: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://lujanventas.com/test.php in my site.

How can I do it aside from an AJAX call? Can it be done without JS?

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a server side script that reads the content of the file and echos it

this is an example for such script in php:

```
 $ids = "http://lujanventas.com/test.php";
 $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=".urlencode($ids);
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
 foreach($data[$ids]["comments"]["data"] as $comment){
     echo $comment["message"]."<br /><br />";
 }
```